# Проблема с проверкой формы авторизации

Tags: php, html, форма, регистрация

День добрый, обращаюсь к знатокам PHP. Со вчерашнего дня на сайте появилась проблема с входом и авторизацией. Я подебажил и выяснил, проблема в том, что не выполняется условие if ( isset( $data['do_signup'] ) ), несмотря на то, что кнопка нажата. Прошу вас уделить внимание и посмотреть, в чем же проблема. Подключение к базе данных идёт, всё остальное нормально. $data (это $_POST) не принимает в себя никаких значений. Заранее спасибо.

```
    <?
# Header Include
$title = 'Stock Up - Sign Up';
$description = 'Register new account';
$ogTitle = 'StockUP - Sign Up';

// TopBar
$AZ = 'lga';
$EN = 'activeL';
$RU = 'lga';
$AZL = 'lgaa';
$ENL = 'activeLL';
$RUL = 'lgaa';

// NavBar
$home = 'HOME';
$categories = 'BROWSE';
$services = 'SERVICES';
$faq = 'FAQ';
$feedback = 'FEEDBACK';

include "header.php";

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_user']) ) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">'.'window.location.href="'.'../pages/account.php'.'";'.'</script>';
}

# Database

$data = $_POST;

if ( isset( $data['do_signup'] ) ) {
    $errors = array();
    if ($data['fName'] == '' ) {
        $errors[] = 'Fill your Name!';
    }

    if (trim($data['email']) == '' ) {
        $errors[] = 'Fill your E-Mail!';
    }

    if ($data['password'] == '' ) {
        $errors[] = 'Fill your Password!';
    }

    if ($data['password_repeat'] != $data['password'] ) {
        $errors[] = 'Passwords do not match!';
    }

    if ($data['terms'] == '' ) {
        $errors[] = 'Accept the Term and Conditions!';
    }

    if (R::count('users', "email = ?", array($data['email'])) > 0) {
        $errors[] = 'User with this E-Mail address already exists!';
    }

    if ( empty($errors) ) {
        $user = R::dispense('users');
        $user->first_name = $data['fName'];
        $user->last_name = $data['lName'];
        $user->email = $data['email'];
        $user->password = password_hash($data['password'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $user->join_date = time();
        R::store( $user );
        $success = 'You are successfully registered!';
        $userconfirm = R::findOne('users', 'email = ?', array($data['email']));
        $_SESSION['logged_user'] = $userconfirm;
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">'.'window.location.href="'.'../pages/account.php'.'";'.'</script>';
    } else {
        $error = array_shift($errors);
    }


}
?>

<section class="breadcumb_area" style="background: url('../img/signupb.jpg') no-repeat scroll center center / cover;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                <div class="breadcumb_section">
                    <div class="page_title">
                        <h3>Sign Up</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="page_pagination">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="../index.php">Home</a></li>
                            <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                            <li>Sign Up</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

    <section class="login">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
                    <div class="login-panel widget">
                        <div class="login-body">
                            <form action="signup.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <div style="margin: 5px 0;"><b style="color: red;"><?echo $error;?></b><b style="color: green;"><?echo $success;?></b></div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">First name (Name of the company) <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                    <input class="form-control" name="fName" type="text" placeholder="First name" value="<?echo $data['fName'];?>">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Last Name (Optional)</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" name="lName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?echo $data['lName'];?>">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Email <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                    <input class="form-control" name="email" type="email" placeholder="mail@example.com" value="<?echo $data['email'];?>">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Password <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                    <input class="form-control" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Confirm Password <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                    <input class="form-control" name="password_repeat" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary pull-left">
                                    <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="terms">
                                    <label for="checkbox2">
                                        I Agree with <a href="../pages/terms.php">Terms and Conditions</a> and <a href="../pages/privacy.php">Privacy Policy</a>
                                    </label>
                                <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 15px;">
                                    <button class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" name="do_signup">Sign Up</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="text-center margin-bottom-none"><a href="signin.php"><strong>Have an account? </strong></a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

<?include 'footer.php'?>
```

Comment: Сейчас обнаружил что $_POST не работает вообще нигде. Кто-то встречался с такой проблемой?

Comment: вы хотите сказать что если в файле  signup.php наверху напишите что нибудь вроде "var_dump($_POST)" он вам вернет пустоту?

Comment: Смотрите откуда $data (это $_POST) принимает данные. Есть ли этот файл и отдает ли он что то